# Calculating tangents for a water surface

Tags: c++, opengl, normals

So I have a project where i am simulating water surface in opengl by modulating a grid in both  x and z using sine waves. I am drawing the normal, tangent & binormal. When modulating the wave in either x or z, all the tangents are drawing correctly, however, modulating in both x & z at the same time ruins the tangents!!! Help. 
here is my code for calculating the partial derivatives & my vector drawing.

```cpp
float dydx = calcDerivativeX(water->waves, x, g.gameTime);
float dydz = calcDerivativeZ(water->waves, z, g.gameTime);
glColor3f(1,0.5,0);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, orange);
    drawVector(x, calcAddSines(water->waves, x, z, g.gameTime), z, 1.0, dydx, 0.0, 0.05);
glColor3f(1,0,1);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, magenta);
drawVector(x, calcAddSines(water->waves, x, z, g.gameTime), z, -dydx, 1.0, -dydz, 0.05);
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
drawVector(x, calcAddSines(water->waves, x, z, g.gameTime), z, 0, dydz, 1.0, 0.05);
```

```cpp
float calcDerivativeX(vector<Wave> waves, float x, float t) {
    float result = 0;

    for(Wave w : waves) {
        result += w.a * w.kx * cosf((w.kx * x) + (w.w*t));
    }
    return result;
}


float calcDerivativeZ(vector<Wave> waves, float z, float t) {
    float result = 0;

    for(Wave w : waves) {
        result += w.a * w.kz * cosf((w.kz * z) + (w.w*t));
    }
    return result;
}

float calcAddSines(vector<Wave> waves, float x, float z, float t) {
    float y = 0;

    for(Wave w: waves) {
        y += calcY(w, x, z, t);
    }

    return y;
}
```

[X modulation only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv6j9.png)

[image]

[Z modulation only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IwrN.png)

[image]

[X & Z modulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3waj.png)

[image]

Comment: *"ruins the tangents[excessive excitement]"* -- ruins them how? They disappear (size goes to zero)? They point in seemingly random directions? Can you reduce this to a [mre] that outputs the values (vector coordinates) of an incorrect tangent (and also indicate the expected tangent)?

Comment: Hello. I have attached some pictures to help. They tangets do not appear to point in the correct direction when being modulated in both axis, however separately they are drawn correctly. Images 1 & 2 are correct. Image 3 the angles are off